# Matlab: how can I replace the slow system() function?

Tags: java, matlab, system-calls

I have a Matlab script that makes many system calls through the `system()` function.
However, I noticed that the function is very slow (has a lot of overhead). For example, the call

```
tic;system('echo');toc;
```

takes on average 0.08 seconds. With lots of system calls overhead becomes unacceptable.

I tried to replace the calls with calls to Java (which I do not know, I am just copying and pasting from somewhere else), as follows

```
runtime=java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
process=runtime.exec('commandStringThatNeedsToBeExecuted');
status=process.waitFor();
```

When it works, it works nicely and the overhead is significantly reduced. However, I have two problems.

First problem: for some commands execution fails (but it does not fail with calls to `system()`), depending on the program I call. In particular (but this is probably irrelevant), when I make calls to `pdflatex`, everything works fine, while when I make calls to ImageMagick's `convert`, execution fails. So, in order to understand these differences in behavior, my first question is: what are the main differences between a Matlab `system()` call and a system call through Java?

Second problem: how do I get the output of the command (I mean what would be displayed on screen if, for example, the command was executed in a DOS command window) that I can get from the second output argument of the `system()` function?

Comment: It might be operating system specific.

Comment: have you checked the environment settings in both configurations?

Comment: Please give a reproducible case that works for 1 method and not for the other.

Answer (score 2):

To get the output, try this:

```
p = java.lang.ProcessBuilder({'cmd', 'arg1', 'arg2'}).start();
reader = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
str = char(java.util.Scanner(reader).useDelimiter('\A').next());
```

You can replace the last line with this:

```
...
sb = java.lang.StringBuilder();
while true;
    line = reader.readLine();
    if isnumeric(line); % Test for NULL
        break;
    else
        sb.append(sprintf('%s\n',char(line)));
    end;
end
str = char(sb.toString());
```

The first is faster if there is a lot of output (matlab's `system()` is very slow in this case), while the second is clearer and more flexible.

As for why it sometimes fails, I'm not sure. Are you constructing the command string in the same way? Do identical command strings sometimes work and sometimes not work? Are you fiddling with the environment?

Answer (score 1):

The differences are as far as i know, system can actively execute cmd commands (Windows) whereas for runtime.exec() commands you have to insert cmd /c beforehand.

To read the output of the process, do the following:

```
p.waitFor();
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
    final StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while (input.ready() && (line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            string.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    return string.toString();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will connect to the outputstream of the process and read it line by line into the stringbuilder.

Comment: Appending cmd /c seems to work in some cases. However, I have tried to play around with it, and I sometimes get weird results. For example, if I try process=runtime.exec('cmd /C dir');
status=process.waitFor(); it remains stuck and I need to kill the process by hand.

Comment: As far as the Java code above is concerned, how should it be passed from Matlab to Java?

Comment: I do not know how to pass code from Matlab to java. I thought "I tried to replace the calls with calls to Java which I do not know" would refer to the java code not on the way to pass it to java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project where I need to run a lot of shell commands and invoke external tools from matlab. This slowness issue caused me a lot of pain.

I've found the above `ProcessBuilder`-based approach very helpful (thanks!) but still needed to tweak various things.
Here's my implementation, hope it's useful for future visitors coming here...

https://github.com/avivrosenberg/matlab-jsystem